# QGIS - actions: open a document - several polygons overlap

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, actions

I inserted an action to a polygon layer in QGIS 3.28.
The action window looks like that
[image]

the action opens a document on my pc.
Here you see the attribute table of the layer
[image]

The action works, when I click on the feature in the map.
Sometimes two polygons overlap. I would like to realize the following idea:
when I click on a point where there is more than one polygon, I would like to select one feature on the basis of specific fields in the attribute table (for example field AZ).

But up to now I could not realize that. When I click on a point where is more than one polygon I get this result:
[image]

The numbers 3 and 5 are the content of the field "fid". But I would like to select based on the content of field "AZ".
Does anybody know a possibility for that?

My OS is LinuxMint21

Comment: What happens if AZ is the first column?

Comment: When I change the shapefile format from gpkg to a ESRI-shapefile and make AZ to the first column, it works for the field AZ. But the idea of @JGH is much more comfortable! In gpkg the fid field is always the first column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `Display name`, which can be any field or expression. Right click on the layer / properties / display.

[image]

[image]

Comment: great! that is exactly what I was looking for. With this display name I even can display several fields. Thanks a lot.